# How can I match text to text from separate columns, then to a row text, and find the intersecting cell?

Tags: excel-formula

In the below example of the sheet - which is enormous - I would like A 3 in Option 3, which in this case is 15.00. I simply want a formula that will generate the 15.

The below sheet is separate from the sheet in which I'm trying to generate the data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHj8Q.jpg)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)